# decltype of template class without the template in C++

Tags: c++, class, templates, decltype, type-deduction

I have a template of template function `template< template< class > class Timg, class T > Timg< T > foo()` for which the compiler cannot deduce types. I can call this function with `foo< object, T >()`, where `object` is a template class. I would like to be able to call this function using `decltype`, or something similar.

Here an example: The first file is `header.h`

```
template< class T >
class object
{
};

template< template< class > class Timg, class T >
Timg< T > foo()
{
        return Timg< T >();
}
```

The second file is `main.cpp`

```
#include "header.h"

int main()
{
        object< float > o;
        auto l_return = foo< object, float >(); // OK
        auto l_return2 = foo< decltype(o), float >(); // What I would like to achieve
        return 0;
}
```

The problem here is that `decltype(o)` returns `object< float >`, but I would like to have only `object`.

How can I deduce type from variable `o` to pass it as template parameter for the function `foo`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`object` is a class template, not a type. Only the instance of a class template is a type. `object<float>` is a type. The template itself is not, it's a template…

I'm not aware of any way to directly deduce the original template a type was instantiated from. What you could do is define a helper class template and partially specialize to match the case that the parameter type is an instance of a template with a single type parameter. That way, you can deduce both, the template as well as the parameter type of a given `object` instance. Inside this helper template, you could then have a member alias template that will give you an `object` instance again as well as an alias to forward the parameter type

```
template <class T>
struct deduce_object_template;

template <template <class> class O, class V>
struct deduce_object_template<O<V>>
{
    template <class T>
    using object_t = O<T>;

    using type = V;
};
```

and then use that to call `foo` like so:

```
foo<deduce_object_template<T>::template object_t, typename deduce_object_template<T>::type>();
```

However, I would seriously question whether there's not a simpler way to achieve whatever it is that you want to achieve. Do you really need to deduce template and argument type? If all you want is create an object of whatever the type parameter was, why not simply define a second template

```
template <class Timg>
Timg foo()
{
    return Timg();
}
```

and call `foo<decltype(o)>();`?

Comment: Thank you, it's a clever workaround!
I gave a simple example. My function looks more like `Timg< Tout > foo(Timg< Tin> x)`, that's why I am not using the second option of only one template parameter.

Comment: In this case, could you not simply have `Timg` be deduced from the function parameter instead of specifying the arguments explicitly: `Timg<bla> foo(const Timg<T>& in) {...}`?

Comment: In your example, it is indeed working because `T` is a type of function parameter. In my context, `T` is in the return type, so it is more similar to `template <template <class> class Timg, class T> Timg<T> foo(const Timg<int>& in) {...}`, which cannot be deduced by the compiler.

Comment: In this case, simply change the order of your template parameters to `template <class T, template <class> class Timg>`. Then you can write `foo<float>(blub);` and have `Timg` be deduced from `blub` and only explicitly specify the argument for the return type.

Comment: That's true, I thought about it. However, it's more natural to write template parameters in the order they appear (it might even be in the coding rules of my company), and, with this question, I anticipate more complex wrappers I'll have to write in the next days.